# Finding conditions such that the following inequality holds.

Tags: linear-algebra, inverse-problems

Let   $ \boldsymbol{J} \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}  $, with $ n>m $ be an invertible full row-rank matrix. Further:
\begin{equation}\label{key}
f=  |\boldsymbol{J}^{-1}  \boldsymbol{1}_{\pm}|_1
\end{equation}
where $\boldsymbol{1}_{\pm} \in  \mathbb{R}^{m \times 1}$ is a vector where each element is either 1 or minus 1, $ \boldsymbol{J}^{-1}  $ is any inverse, and $|(\cdot)|_1$ is the absolute value norm.

Now, is it possible to find a factor $ c_1 $, (as function of properties of $ \boldsymbol{J} $) such that $f<c_1 $ for any $\boldsymbol{1}_{\pm}$. ?

Feel free to assert any new conditions on $\boldsymbol{J}$ to make this work.

Edit :
 If it makes it easier to solve, I am happy to receive answers where $\boldsymbol{1}_{\pm}|_1$ is simplified to $\boldsymbol{1}$ (i.e. a one-only vector).

Comment: You need to clarify your question. the right hand side is a set of values.

Comment: Edited, and added a variant with only positive values in $\boldsymbol{1}$.